Cannot access database from PHP script when called from web page
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, nginx 1.18.0, mariadb 15.1 and PHP 8.1.2.
Here the code of my database.php:
<?php

$SERVER_APP = "localhost";
$DATABASE_APP = "mydb";
$USERNAME_APP = "root";
$PASSWORD_APP = "password";

function db_connect() {
    global $SERVER_APP, $DATABASE_APP, $USERNAME_APP, $PASSWORD_APP;

    try {
        $dbApp = new PDO("mysql:host=$SERVER_APP;dbname=$DATABASE_APP", $USERNAME_APP, $PASSWORD_APP);
        $dbApp->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbApp->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        echo "Connected to db";
        return $dbApp;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if I execute this code from command line:
php -r "require 'database.php'; db_connect();"

it works fine:

Connected to db

And I can also connect to the SQL database using:
mysql -u root -p

and entering the same password.
But when the above function is called from a PHP script, like this samples.php:
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-type: application/json");
require 'database.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dbApp = db_connect();  
$stmt = $dbApp->prepare("SELECT * FROM sensors WHERE sampled > (now() - interval 24 hour) ORDER BY sampled;");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results);

$dbApp = null;

which, in turn, is called from the index.php:
// url = 'samples.php'
function get_samples(url) {
    fetch(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":3001" + url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        // do something
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}

the connection to the database fails:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Of course the database is on the same server, i.e. localhost.
What could cause the access denied error if the very same script is working when called manually from console?

mariadb 15.1 are you sure?
The issue you're facing is likely related to the way the MySQL root user is configured to authenticate in Ubuntu.
By default, on Ubuntu systems, the root MySQL user often uses socket-based authentication instead of password-based authentication when accessed from the local machine. This means that when you connect using the command line, the system authenticates the user as root based on the operating system login session, without needing a password.
However, when the PHP script is executed via a web server (like Nginx or Apache), it doesn't authenticate via the socket and thus fails to authenticate with the password you have provided.
Instead of using the root user, which is not recommended for web applications, create a new MySQL user specifically for your application, and grant it the necessary permissions.
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;


About the version: mariadb --version mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.18-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper. It is 15.1 if I'm not wrong

Your mariadb server version is 10.6.18. 15.1 is a version of the mariadb client.
